# Establecer Jframe Principal [NO es añadir, es establecer ]

Tags: java, jframe

Buenas!

Tengo un proyecto con varios jFrame. El problema es que cuando compilo el proyecto y me genera mi .jar, al ejecutarlo, se abre otro jFrame que no es mi principal.

¿Como le digo a mi proyecto cual es el main jFrame?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resuelto.

En netbeans [El IDE que utilizo], en las propiedades del proyecto [click derecho, propiedades], en la seccion RUN, te deja elegir la clase principal. Luego al compilarlo, asi se lanza.

Comment: Pero si tienes un metodo main el cual configuras manualmente, puedes lanzar los frames que quieras, lo cual seria lo mas recomendable, eso si. sin que vaya en contravia de la logica de tu programa

Answer (score 1):

muchas gracias por el aporte 
comentar que cuando ejecutas el proyecto se abre un JFrame que no quieres lo que debes hacer es ir al codigo del JFrame que se abre y el la parte de asta abajo

```
        public void run() {
            new login_menu().setVisible(true);
        }
```

donde esta adentante de new el nombre del JFrame debes poner el que quieres que sea el principal.

espero les sirva

Answer (score 0):

espero haber entendido tu pregunta

si creaste el jframe me forma automatica se crea el metodo main es decir, si creas 4 jframe abra 4 metodos main asi que borra todos los metodos main que vienen en los jframe y creas una clase que lo unico que contenga sea el metodo main, o bien pudes dejar el metodo main en el jframe que es el principal.

```
public class main{
public static void main String[]args{
//Jframe es el nombre de tu ventana que quieres que sea la principal
Jframe principal=new Jframe();
principal.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

suponiendo que la ventana principal conecta con las ventanas secundarias.
espero que te sirva.
deberias poner fragmento de tu codigo y asi poder entender mejor tu problema.